# Can I suppress the 'i' symbol in an information toast?

Tags: javascript, toastr

Is it possible to suppress the 'i' symbol in an information toast in tostr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hide the background image with your CSS

```css
body #toast-container>.toast-info {
  background-image: none;
}
```

Comment: This works well. however, there seems to be an empty space. So, if I have "I my message", it shows "  my message" instead of displaying, "my message"

Comment: So inspect the element further and figure out how to remove the margin or padding that is there.